# where do i find option to change light bounce?

Tags: rendering, light

i'm sure this is a simple question but i've just started with blender. I see that I can change the number of light bounces to reduce render time, but I can't find that option in the newest version?

Comment: I expect you are referring to the global render setting that is only available in cycles (as shown by gandalf3), If you have trouble finding that bounce setting it may be that you don't have cycles enabled, check the render menu next to the blender logo at the top of the window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's still where it always has been, in *Properties > Render > Light Paths > Bounces*:

[image]

Comment: I did have to change to cycles rendering instead of blender render.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Change the **render engine to cycles.** Then only you will be able to view the light paths option. Eevee renderer has only has indirect lighting settings.

Hope it helps